# How to reference Boolean java class from kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

As far as I understand `Boolean::class.java` gives me `Boolean.TYPE`, but not `Boolean.class`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To reference Java primitive and boxed types, use:

- [`Boolean::class.javaPrimitiveType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java-primitive-type.html) (equivalent to Java `Boolean.TYPE`)
- [`Boolean::class.javaObjectType`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java-object-type.html) (equivalent to Java `Boolean.class`)